# How to print/examine floating point registers?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, sse

Let's say I have the following:

```
c: .float 3.14
movss c(%rip), %xmm0
```

How can I examine that register in a readable manner? For example, I can get the whole debug output, but not just a friendly number:

```
>>> p/f $xmm0
$2 = {
  v4_float = {[0] = 3.1400001, [1.40129846e-45] = 0, [2.80259693e-45] = 0, [4.20389539e-45] = 0},
  v2_double = {[0] = 5.3286132608536752e-315, [1.40129846e-45] = 0},
  v16_int8 = {[0] = -61, [1.40129846e-45] = -11, [2.80259693e-45] = 72, [4.20389539e-45] = 64, [5.60519386e-45] = 0 <repeats 12 times>},
  v8_int16 = {[0] = -2621, [1.40129846e-45] = 16456, [2.80259693e-45] = 0, [4.20389539e-45] = 0, [5.60519386e-45] = 0, [7.00649232e-45] = 0, [8.40779079e-45] = 0, [9.80908925e-45] = 0},
  v4_int32 = {[0] = 3.1400001, [1.40129846e-45] = 0, [2.80259693e-45] = 0, [4.20389539e-45] = 0},
  v2_int64 = {[0] = 5.3286132608536752e-315, [1.40129846e-45] = 0},
  uint128 = 3.93143274128552720884e-4942
}
```

How would I just get the value `3.14` without all the other lines of output?

Hopefully something like I can get from examining the variable itself:

```
>>> x/f &c
0x6000df:   3.1400001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dot-notation to print the specific items. For example, to print the `float` and `double` value:

```
>>> p $xmm0.v4_float[0]
$4 = 3.1400001
>>> p $xmm0.v2_double[0]
$5 = 5.3286132608536752e-315
```

Obviously the `double` is meaningless here, but used to show that any of the `v4_float`, `v2_double`, `v16_int8`, ... should work.